# MySQL Inventory / Stock Average Costing

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table called "entries" where I save daily sale and purchase transactions / entries. "entries" table looks like:

---Entries Table---

```
EntryDate    EntryType    Item    Qty    Rate    Cost    Sale
2016-01-01   Purchase     Apples  10     10      100     -
2016-01-02   Purchase     Apples  20     15      300     -
2016-01-02   Purchase     Oranges 20     15      300     -
2016-01-02   Sale         Apples  5      20      **      100
....
....
```

Now I need to run a query to **update** the [cost] column in above table where [EntryType] is 'Sale'. Cost will be calculated using Weighted Average Method i.e. Current Sale Row Cost = sum ( all previous costs of purchases - all previous [calculated]costs of sales ) / sum( all previous qty of purchases - all previous qty of sales ).

I Need update query

```
 update entires set ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  C# is more associated with SQL Server as are square braces for column names.

Comment: I just added square braces to differentiate it from other text... Yes I am using MySQL with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I got this right,

```
Cost = (Sum of cost previous purchases -Sum of cost previous sales)/(sum of qty previous purchases -Sum of qty previous sales)
```

Ok Fist I like to do a small suggestion to make everyone's life easy. You need to record one type as negative. Say you mark purchases as negative (both cost and qty)

```
EntryDate    EntryType    Item    Qty    Rate    Cost    Sale
2016-01-01   Purchase     Apples  -10     10      -100     -
2016-01-02   Purchase     Apples  -20     15      -300     -
2016-01-02   Purchase     Oranges -20     15      -300     -
2016-01-02   Sale         Apples  5      20      **      100
....
....
```

Now loop though each sale row and run below query (Hoping there is a ID column of something that help to identify the order):

```
Cost = SELECT SUM(`ID`)/SUM(`TaxID`) FROM category  WHERE `TaxID` < currentID
```

Use this and UPDATE cost

Comment: But how can i loop and update through mysql query?     someone also told me query like:    update entries e1, entries e2 set cost = (sum(e2.cost)/sum(e2.qty)) where e1.entrytype = 'sale' and e2.EntryDate < e1.EntryDate;    Is it correct query????????

Comment: From what I understood that query is not correct. And looping you can do with a stored procedure